# kohana 3.0 resize image before uploading?

Tags: php, image, resize, kohana-3, crop

I want to upload some images to the server, but first of all i want them croped, and resized to some certain dimensions.

Now i am doing the simple upload and save like that:

```
$header_image = Upload::save($_FILES['sale_picture_header'],NULL,APPPATH.'media'.'/');
$image_header = Model::factory('image');                                
$image_header->name = basename($header_image);
$image_header->save();
```

(excluding the validation).

How can i crop or resize the image to some desired dimensions, in Kohana 3.0? I couldn't find any relevant documentation regarding that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with the image package:

```
// Resize to 200 pixels on the shortest side
$image->resize(200, 200);

// Resize to 200x200 pixels, keeping aspect ratio
$image->resize(200, 200, Image::INVERSE);

// Resize to 500 pixel width, keeping aspect ratio
$image->resize(500, NULL);

// Resize to 500 pixel height, keeping aspect ratio
$image->resize(NULL, 500);

// Resize to 200x500 pixels, ignoring aspect ratio
$image->resize(200, 500, Image::NONE);
```

source:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Image#resize

Comment: i do like this:   $header_image = Upload::save($_FILES['sale_picture_header'], NULL, APPPATH . 'media' . '/');
    $header_image = Image::factory($header_image)->resize(80, 60)->save();
 and though it throws me no error, it stops parsing after the last line.

Comment: Your last line must end with `->render(NULL, 80)` (for example) instead of `->save()`. Also, the `render` method returns the image binary data, so you must put that into a file, not assign it to a variable. You can use PHP's file_put_contents function, ie, `file_put_contents('your/desired/file/path', Image::factory($upload_saved_image_path)->resize(80, 60)->render());`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library, or the [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library for image manipulation.

Also note that these are strictly server-side, and will not happen *before* upload. For that you'd need some client-side plugin capable of image manipulation such as Flash or Java.

Answer (score 0):

I found something very interesting. The question was, how to perform this action, "resize then crop" an image to fit perfectly a determined box, and this is the solution:

```
Image::factory($file)
    ->resize(128, 149, Image::PRECISE)
    ->crop(128, 149)
    ->save(DOCROOT.$filename);
```

Note that you must use Image::PRECISE, instead of IMAGE::AUTO.

Hope this helps someone.